# Static resources response with 503 in Nginx over k8s Ingress

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I have setup an Ingress for my nginx service,and I can access this service(`my-domain.com`) with a `200` response.But it always returns `503` when the html page trying to get its static resources(`my-domain.com/foo/static/`). But everything goes right when I simply pull my image and expose the port on local machine.

pieces of code:

```
nginx.conf
location / {
   root html;
   index index.html;
}

ingress.yml
http:
  paths:
    - path : /
    backend:
      serviceName: nginx
      servicePort: 8000

directories and fies inner nginx/html:
- html
  - foo
    - static
      - css
      - js
      - image
    index.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `nginx.conf` I should Specify `server_name` the same as k8s `service` name in the same k8s cluster.